# Model binding fof List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently Use a ViewModel to show DropDown items, thanks to proprety I use to fill dropdown's (professionsSelect). value are stored into a list (professions).

Here is the sample of my DocumentViewModel:

```
[Required]
public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> professionsSelect { get; set; }
```

Here's Profession Model sample:

```
public class Profession
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

Now, for instance, to insert data into DB, I use a Model, corresponding to the Model. I use a Mapper to transform VM to Model:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DocumentViewModel, BE.Document>();
                IList<BE.Document> destination = Mapper.Map<IList<BE.Document>>(document);
```

But the problem is that When I receive VM on the controller, there is no data into destination  list:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DocumentViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {...}
}
```

How Can the model bindong I fill the List IList of the ViewModel?

Here is how I do to show data ot user on creation form:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.professions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.professions, Model.professionsSelect, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.professions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

One possible solution should be to create a new property to viewModel int[] ProfessionIds but it is unclear, 3 properties for one fidls, that's definitiverly too mutch for me.

Thanks to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects (in your case `Profession`). It only posts back an array of value types (the values of the selected options).

Your model needs a property (say)

```
public int[] SelectedProfessions { get; set; } // or List<int>
```

assuming your wanting to post back a collection of the `Profession.id`

Then the view will be

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedProfessions, Model.professionsSelect, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: and then just after Model.IsValid, I can call viewModel.fillLists() in order to fill lists from Ids ? is this really the cleanest way? thanks

Comment: or in JS, handle the onclick button and create a table with selected ids in ordeert o create IEnumerable ? that will be not clean to maintain but clean for the model...

Comment: Don't what `viewModel.fillLists()` is not sure what your asking.

Comment: Are you wanting to display a filtered list of get a collection of `Profession` based on the posted values, then in the controller method you will need to call you database again and get them based on the values in `model.SelectedProfessions`

Comment: Where viewModel.fillLists() method take all int[] SelectedProfessions to fill List<Profession> professions in order to have clean model after Mapper (an then save model into DB)... is it the cleanest for you?

Comment: Sound good to me, although not sure why you need a separate function for this - its just a one line LINQ query

Comment: Because there is more fields than professions in this case (that I need to create new Objects from ids ) :-) ok good thanks again Stephen